# Rails model generating lots of sql queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization

I have a model (LineItem) which is a child of another (Invoice). Within LineItem, I delegate a method which references an attribute in Invoice. Whenever this method is run, it always runs several SQL queries...as if it's re-searching Invoice all over again

Model "Invoice"
- contains attribute "created_at"
- contains `default_scope includes(:line_items, :payments, :sales_person)`

Model "LineItem"
- contains `delegate :created_at, :to => :invoice, :prefix => true`
- another method contains:

```
@tax_rate ||= (category.to_sym == :books ? invoice_created_at.federal_tax_rate : invoice_created_at.tax_rate)
```

It is in this method that the following is generated (using the 'mini-profiler' gem):

```
SELECT `invoices`.* FROM `invoices`  WHERE `invoices`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items`  WHERE `line_items`.`invoice_id` IN (4)
SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  WHERE `items`.`id` IN (31, 15)
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories`  WHERE `categories`.`id` IN (6, 1) ORDER BY name
SELECT `payments`.* FROM `payments`  WHERE `payments`.`invoice_id` IN (4)
SELECT `payment_types`.* FROM `payment_types`  WHERE `payment_types`.`id` IN (1) ORDER BY name
SELECT `sales_people`.* FROM `sales_people`  WHERE `sales_people`.`id` IN (1) ORDER BY name
```

It does this for every line item. All of those SELECT statements already happen in bulk well before the invoice_created_at.*tax_rate methods are called...

```
SELECT `invoices`.* FROM `invoices`  WHERE (created_at between '2011-05-01 04:00:00' and '2013-02-06 04:59:59')
SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items`  WHERE `line_items`.`invoice_id` IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
```

What can I do to ensure all of these SELECT queries don't have to be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can stop using `default_scope includes` - it isn't needed for typical cases and probably not in your case either.

Secondly, and more importantly, you should declare the `:inverse_of` attribute on your associations to minimize reloading objects that are already in memory:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :inverse_of => :invoice
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice, :inverse_of => :line_items
end
```

Comment: Excellent! That did it for me. I do find it strange that it isn't this way by default.